# How can I reduce the file size of a video from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, video, codecs

I want to reduce the size of a video size. The video may be .flv, .avi, etc. I want it done from the terminal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should start with a caveat, that transcoding between lossy media formats will generally involve loss of quality.

There are lots of options here:

- Convert older formats (`MPEG-1`, `DivX 3` etc) to newer and more efficient codecs (eg `x264`, `theora`) which will generally mostly preserve video/audio quality in a smaller output.
- Reduce the target bitrate or target output size, improving size at the cost of reproduction quality.
- Reduce the video dimensions, allowing similar reproduction quality at lower total size.

Unless you have strong reasons for another choice, `x264` for video and `aac` for audio in an `mp4` container is a good choice for quality and reasonably wide compatibility (but you should encode something short and try it on anything you'll want to play it on - getting widely playable transcoded results remains an exercise in witchcraft).

I find the current command serves me fairly well for converting older formats:

```
avconv -y -i INPUT -pre:v libx264-slower -b:a 96k -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc OUTPUT.mp4
```

You can scale down the image size by adding `-vf scale=iw*0.5:ih*0.5` before the output name, or set a video bitrate `-b:v`, or play with multi-pass options... but mostly the above will produce a reasonable outcome.

Comment: On 16.04 "Preset libx264-slower specified for stream 0:0, but could not be opened."