# How to apply lossy compression on a file/video using the command-line?

Tags: command-line, video, compression

How can I apply lossy compression on a video using the command-line?

When I use the default compression tool available in Ubuntu (ie. package the video into a tar.gz, zip, etc. file), I don't get much of a difference in size, so I suppose they use lossless compression?

Comment: `gzip` and `zip` use lossless compression. The files don't shrink because their encoding uses compression already (already compressed data usually don't shrink, they might even grow). The only solution would be re-encoding them with a lower quality (e.g. using `ffmpeg`). Which video encodings are we talking about?

Comment: @kos mp4, webm, and flv

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/249918/380067

Comment: Also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg